# angular read post response header not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i'm trying to code login page with **angular** and **spring boot** but i cannot read the post response with angular..

- the  form login

```
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin(f.value)">
    <input [(ngModel)]="login.email" value="admin" type="text" name="email" id="email" ngModule placeholder="email"><br>
    <input [(ngModel)]="login.password" value="root" type="text" name="password" id="password" ngModule placeholder="password"><br>

    <button type="submit" >submit </button>

    </form>
```

- the ts component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EntrepriseService } from '../services/entreprise.service';
import {Entreprise} from '../modules/entreprise';
import {Collaborator} from '../modules/collaborator';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


export interface Login {
  email:String;
  password:String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

login:Login={
  email:"admin",
  password:"root"
}


  constructor(private auth:AuthService) { }

  onLogin(data){
    console.log(data);
    this.auth.login(data).subscribe(res =>{
        console.log(res.headers);
        console.log(res.headers.get("Authorization"));
     },err =>{

       console.log(err);
     });
  }
```

- the service authentication

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

url:string="http://localhost:8080/";
login(data){
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url+"login",data,{observe:'response'})
}
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
}
```

and this is the result in console when i click on submit button
[image]

and this is how the response looks on **network** section using developing tools on the borwsers
[image]

the question is : how can i get the header of post response  .. i wanna get the Authorization

Answer (score 2):

i fixed the problem by adding this line in spring boot ..

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers");
```

i was writing **Header** instead of **HEADERS**
typing mistake